# Has anyone encountered 'Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster..'error

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I did some research on this and have tried out inserting:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="A4B12CCDD50E95F8GB9GFH6JKAT4Y0U0I2OF2DF2AAFE5AB46189C,IsolateApps" validation="AES" validationKey="480CDF2AS9S9AS5CFDGF0GHFH9JJH4KHKAKLJ2L9F3SAS82A6C16911A29EF48903783F94529C21570AACB72766FB38CD4CE7B85B0ACE3149DC5FC1CCF1AA1CECE3579659996593B06,IsolateApps"/>
```

as a solution to this error:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

This time I get an error.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Then it marks out the line in Config source:

```
<add name="DemographicDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DemoGraph.csdl|res://*/DemoGraph.ssdl|res://*/DemoGraph.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=207.27.57.76,1433;initial catalog=DemographicDB;persist security info=False;user  id=west;pwd=westhouseit;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<machineKey decryptionKey="A4B12CCDD50E95F8GB9GFH6JKAT4Y0U0I2OF2DF2AAFE5AB46189C,IsolateApps" validation="AES" validationKey="480CDF2AS9S9AS5CFDGF0GHFH9JJH4KHKAKLJ2L9F3SAS82A6C16911A29EF48903783F94529C21570AACB72766FB38CD4CE7B85B0ACE3149DC5FC1CCF1AA1CECE3579659996593B06,IsolateApps"/>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Is the machine key tag well constructed? I put it in a tag all by itself.
I am hosting the application on an online host so I cannot generate any machine code with IIS 7.0. I have raised several tickets to no avail. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Doesnt the forbdden 403 mean you dont have permission to view the webpage? Even when connected.

Comment: Sorry its not 403 forbidden error. I will edit now!

Comment: Ok, Mike, I will endeavour to indicate the answers that porvide solution to my challenges if that is what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can manually specify the key and include the `IsolateApps` option. It must be `Autogenerate,IsolateApps` or a specific value without the `IsolateApps` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can manually specify the key and include the `IsolateApps` option. It must be `Autogenerate,IsolateApps` or a specific value without the `IsolateApps` option.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what the issue is that IIS doesnt have access to your webconfig file.

Try this out, if it doesnt work take a look at the link below to see if you can try and error your issue.

```
1.Open control panel
2.Click on” program” link (not uninstall programs)
3.Click” turn windows features on/off” link
4.locate” Internet Information services IIS” in the pop up window and expand its node
5.Expand the” World Wide Web Service” node
6.Expand “Application Development Features” node
7.check the check box of”ASP.NET”
8.Then click ok button
```

Below is a very interesting link that would help you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Answer (score 1):

Below is a link to a bug report that references Windows 2003 and .Net framework 3.5 and a web garden setup.

Nothing says that the problem is restricted to Win 2003 or even framework 3.5.  In a web garden situation, one can imagine that the viewstate errors would happen VERY frequently, not just when the pool recycles (as we experienced).

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/412881/net-3-5-installer-breaks-web-gardens-when-used-with-custom-application-pool-identity

To fix the metabase and registry permissions issues, we simply executed the following on our web server:

\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ga domain\useraccount

We then recycled the app pool one more time to regenerate the viewstate validation key.

Whether or not this works in your situation will depend on specific details of your situation.